# font to span converter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using ckeditor; and currently theres a bug that makes the editor replace `<span>` tags with `<font>` ([I made a post on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945024/ckeditor-replacing-span-with-font-tags)). I submitted a bug report explaining the issue but can't wait for a fix, so for now I would like to implement my own. I'm wondering whats the reliable way to convert `<font>` tags to `<span>` tags seamlessly. For example if I have the following:

```
<font face="Raleway" size="18" color="blue" class="makers styles">Simple Text</font>
```

The span equivalent would be this:

```
<span style="font-family:Raleway; size:18px; color:blue;" class="makers styles">Simple Text</span>
```

Comment: Probably an idea to copy and paste it into a text editor that allows for regex find & replace and build a regex string to convert all the attributes into inline styling. Might I suggest using regex101.com to test and build the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$(function() {

    // Your WYSIWYG content string
    var content = "";

    $('font', content).each(function() {

        // Append a new <span> after this <font>
        $(this).after(function() {
            var span = $('<span>').text($(this).text());

            if(this.hasAttribute('face')) {
                span.css('font-family', $(this).attr('face'));
            }
            if(this.hasAttribute('size')) {
                span.css('font-size', $(this).attr('size') + 'px');
            }
            if(this.hasAttribute('color')) {
                span.css('color', $(this).attr('color'));
            }
            if(this.hasAttribute('class')) {
                span.attr('class', $(this).attr('class'));
            }

            return span;
        });

        // Remove this <font>
        $(this).remove();

    });

});
```